# Password hash in php registration and login not working

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, sha1, password-hash

I'm using password salt to hash users' password during registration, also use the same method in login but it always show me incorrect password please can someone tell me what is the error.
If i remove the password salt it will work fine but i need to secure the password.

**Here is my registration code**

```
<?php

include($root . 'database_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username']; //else assign it a variable
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

        $salt = "@g26jQsG&nh*&#8v";
        $passcode =  sha1($password.$salt);
        $name = $username;
        $pass = $passcode;
        $mail = $email;
        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `username`, `password`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ( '$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$numbers')";

            $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query_insert_user);
            if (!$result_insert_user) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }   

    mysqli_close($db_conn); //Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.

?>
```

**Login page**

```
 <?php

        if ($_POST) {

          $salt = "@g26jQsG&nh*&#8v";
          $password =  sha1($_POST['password'].$salt);

          $logdb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userdb', 'root', 'pass');
          $logdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $stmt = $logdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
          $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);
          $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
          $stmt->execute();

        $atributes = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($atributes) {
            session_start();

             $username  = $atributes->username;
             $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
             $active = $atributes->active;
             $email = $atributes->email;
    if($active==0){
    echo '<table><td width="50px" valign="top"><i class="fa fa-ban mail2"></i></td><td><div>Authentication Error! Your account is not verified please verify your email.<br/>
    <small>Need more help? Please contact the systems administrator.</small></div></td></table>';}
    else{
            header("location: index.php");
    } 

          } else {
             header("location: login.php?else=0&n");
              //incorrect
            }

        }   

           else {
         header("location: login.php?false=1&n");
              echo '<form name="login" action="" method="POST">
          Username: <br />
          <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
          Password: <br />
          <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
          <a href="signup.php">Register</a></form>';


          }
        $logdb=null;
    ?>
```

Comment: Salt needs to be unique for each user. Also, your registration code is wide open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Php provides native support for password hashing and verification. Please use `password_hash()` function as it is more secure and easy to use. It has options to use with salt.

Please Refer to

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
>
> http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/

Sha1 is a compromised algorithm and if anyone knows your salt, he will be able to break the password.

Registration Code will change as:

```
    $passcode =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // leave the salt as this function will automatically generate a secure one for you
    $name = $username;
    $pass = $passcode;
```

**Login code**

```
    // Please get user's password as hash in $password_hash and plain text password from user. Then use password_verify function (native function) to verify the password
if(password_verify($_POST['password'] , $password_hash)
{
     // correct password
}
else
{
     // wrong password
}
```

Comment: Please give me example how how i can do it

Comment: @Micheal done. Please make sure you are using php > 5.5

Comment: I did it this way in registration `$passcode =  password_hash($password);
 $name = $username;
 $pass = $passcode;` it insert empty password please give me clear example

Comment: Are you receiving password in $_POST['password']?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using password salt to **encrypt users password** during registration

[No you're not](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Your code says:

```
$salt = "@g26jQsG&nh*&#8v";
$passcode =  sha1($password.$salt);
```

SHA1 is not encryption, it's a hash function. **Hashing is not encryption.**

Hashing is a one-way function that takes an infinite number of possible values and maps them to a finite number of values, in such a way that's hard to go back from the finite to the corresponding value from the infinite.

This is also a very insecure way to store passwords. See: [How to safely store a password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password). (The other answer is correct: use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.)

Additionally:

```
$username = $_POST['username']; //else assign it a variable
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// SNIP //
$query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `username`, `password`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ( '$name', '$pass', '$mail', '$numbers')";
```

Your registration code is insecure. You may want to learn [how to prevent SQL injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide). And [application security in general](https://github.com/paragonie/awesome-appsec), for that matter.